# How can I reverse the order of items returned from Model.find({});

Tags: javascript, mongoose

This command

```
Model.find({});
```

is used by Mongoose go return all the models of type Model.  However whenever I display the array of JSON that it is returned it is in reverse order.

I could just loop through the array backwards but was curious if there is a way to have Mongoose return the array so that the last model I added would be the first returned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sort on the published date. How i did

```
 vObj
      .find()
      .sort({ publishedAt: "-1" })
      .limit(50)
      .then((videos) => {
        //skip it 
      })
```

You need to add timestamp to your model.This is how i did.

```
var videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true, },
    description: String,
    imageurl:{type:String,required:true,},
    publishedAt:{type:String,required:true,},

},{ timestamps: true });
```

Comment: What does publishedAt: "-1" do?

Comment: publishedAt is a key in data object. -1 indicates to sort all object according to descending order, bigger to smaller. (in our case time is used so it sorts object as newer to older). publishedAt is not added by mongodb timestamps, it is added by me. Timestamps have following keys: 1.createdAt 2.UpdatedAt and may be more.